# search results showing old title of renamed content

Tags: search, search-results, enterprise-search

Using SharePoint 2010 enterprise search.

A web has been renamed eg. from Risk to Threat.
When I search for the term "Risk" a broken link to the old url "~Site/risk" is still displayed at the top of the search results.

I've already done multiple incremental AND Full crawls, and nothing seems to help.

Is there any solution that **DOES NOT require resetting the index** that would allow me to remove the old link from search results?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it is related to the **ErrorDeleteCountAllowed** and **ErrorDeleteIntervalAllowed** of the crawl deletion policies.

More detail here: http://blogs.technet.com/b/tothesharepoint/archive/2011/01/20/managing-crawl-deletion-policies-for-sharepoint-server-2010.aspx

Comment: I changed the value for **ErrorDeleteCountAllowed=1** and **ErrorDeleteIntervalAllowed=1** and then full crawled, but it still appears in the search result. I also waited for more than hours and then done full crawl but it still appears in the search result. Babu

Answer (score 4):

You can do it using *Search Results Removal* (under *Queries and Results* section) from the Search Administration page.
Enter the old url here and it will be removed immediately.